# C++ list iterator arithmetic?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm trying to create a set of loops with iterators and I'm having trouble with some iterator arithmetic (that I thought was possible but is not working).

Below is some code:

```
  for (list<Term>::iterator itr = final.begin(); itr != final.end(); itr++) {
        for(list<Term>::iterator j = itr + 1; j != final.end(); j++) {
            cout << itr->term << " " << j->term;
            if(itr->term == j->term) {
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is have j start at the next place in the queue along from itr. The reason for this is I don't want to check the first item against itself. The error itself comes from the part in the code where I have specified `itr + 1`. Now I was sure with pointers you could do arithmetic like this, why is it not working with the list iterator (which is essentially the same thing?)

The error I am getting from my IDE is as follows: `main.cpp:237:48: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘itr + 1’`. Again I thought you could do this sort of arithmetic on iterators so I'm not really sure what to do to make this work, is there an alternate implementation I could try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`list` has bidirectional iterators, that doesn't support `operator +`. You can use `std::advance`, or `std::next` in C++11.

```
for (list<Term>::iterator j = next(itr); j != final.end(); ++j)
```

or

```
list<Term>::iterator j = itr;
advance(j, 1); // or ++j
for (; j != final.end(); ++j)
```

Comment: Why would you call `std::advance` with a constant argument of 1, when in all cases where that's possible, so is `++`?

Answer (score 7):

`list` iterators are not random access so you cannot do `+` with them. They are bidirectional iterators so the only movement operations you can do are `--` and `++`. You can either make a copy and use `++` on it, or make a copy and `std::advance(it, 1)`.

For C++11 there is also `std::next` which gives you `it + 1`, without you having to explicitly make a named copy like you do with the others.

Comment: Are you suggesting I make a copy of the internal or external iterator? I'm assuming you mean external loop iterator and then fix it back up once I've got to the end of my loop?

Comment: @Scott you need to make a copy of `itr` and increment it separately, like `list<Term>::iterator j = itr; ++j`. For `std::next` you can just do `list<Term>::iterator j = std::next(itr)` (or `auto j = std::next(itr)` for C++11 which you have if you have `next`)