# C++ List erase up to end()-1 elements in the list

Tags: c++, list, stl, listiterator, stdlist

I have a `std::list<some_object> events` and I would like to delete all elements of that list except the last one. So I thought of doing (as suggested by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946444/c-list-iterator-arithmetic)):

```
std::list<some_object>::iterator it = events.begin(); // Init iterator on top of list
while(it!=*std::advance(events.end(),-1)) events.erase(it++);
```

Unfortunately the above is not working as it produces the error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::_List_iterator<node_info>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::__cxx11::list<node_info>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<node_info>}’
             while(it!=*std::advance(event_heap.end(),-1)){
```

But, isn't [`list::end`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/end/) supposed to return an iterator? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use `std::list::erase`?

Comment: What's wrong with `events.erase(events.begin(), --(events.end()));`?

Comment: You should use `std::list::erase()`, but as an alternative, maybe you could `push_back()` the `back()` item to a temp `std::list`, and then `std::swap()` the temp with your main `std::list`, eg: `std::list<some_object> temp; temp.push_back(events.back()); std::swap(events, temp);` When the temp then goes out of scope, it will free all of the items you did not save.

Comment: adding to Remy's comment, you could move the object into the temp list instead of copying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, isn't list::end supposed to return an iterator?

Yes, but [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) takes non-const reference as its 1st parameter, while `event_heap.end()` is a temporary variable and can't be bound to non-const reference.

And `std::advance` returns nothing (i.e. `void`), so you can't use `operator*` on it or compare it with `it`.

The direct fixing will be like:

```
std::list<some_object>::iterator it = events.begin();
auto one_before_end = events.end();
std::advance(one_before_end, -1); // or --one_before_end;
while (it != one_before_end) events.erase(it++);
```

BTW: [`std::list::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) has an overloading taking iterator range, so you can just:

```
events.erase(events.begin(), one_before_end);
```

Comment: Thanks @songyuanyao and all for your enlightening replies! @NathanOliver @Beta : I forgot to mention that before erasing I need to do some additional operations on individual list elements. Therefore I need to erase the list elements one by one. Hence the `while` loop is probably the most straight forward way to do this. Alternatively, I could use a functor predicate with `std::list::remove_if`...

Answer (score 7):

That's one typical use of [**`std::prev`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev).
If you want to [remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) all elements except the last one, the most idiomatic way to do it is by using [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) (which basically uses `std::advance`) on your end iterator.

```
myList.erase(myList.begin(), std::prev(myList.end()));
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

int main(){
    std::list<int> ls = {3, 5, 9, 2};

    if(!ls.empty())
        ls.erase(ls.begin(), std::prev(ls.end()));

    for(auto x : ls)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
2
```

As Remy Lebeau pointed out in the comment, for non C++11 compiler, you can just use `std::advance()` as explained in [songyuanyao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37403217/1621391)

Comment: Note that `std::prev()` is new in C++11.  For earlier versions, you have to keep using `std::advance()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks, fixed. :-)

Comment: In general you should check `!ls.empty()` before doing `prev(ls.end())` or equivalent